# Can't get images to show up, No file or directory(Mac)

Tags: python, image, file, directory

trying to make a screen for RPS but it can't find the directory, I tried everything but it still doesn't find it.

```
rock = os.path.join('C:/Users/louistenant/Code_RPS/Scissors.jpg')
paper = os.path.join('C:/Users/louistenant/Code_RPS/Scissors.jpg')
scissors = os.path.join('C:/Users/louistenant/Code_RPS/Scissors.jpg')

rock_surface = pygame.image.load(rock).convert()
paper_surface = pygame.image.load(paper).convert()
scissors_surface = pygame.image.load(scissors).convert()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))
captions = pygame.display.set_caption("Rock Paper Sissors")
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
screen.blit(scissors,(0,0))
screen.blit(paper,(0,100))
screen.blit(rock,(0,200))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You titled the question as a Mac issue, but your path in `os.path.join()` is that of a Windows system (as indicated by `C:\Users\blablabla`).

To fix your issue, you just have to link it to the correct path. You can do this by finding the absolute path, usually from home (`~/`) directory

OR if you are running your python code in the terminal / place where you know the path of, you can also use relative path as well.

Here's a [link](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/file-interaction.html) you could find more information about paths in Python. Although this is for Python2.7, the more general information is applicable to Python3 as well